# Multi search box using like operator

Tags: php, sql-like

I have 3 search boxes and the user can type information into any 3 or all 3 search boxes.

```
$user = $_POST['user']; 
$firstname = $_POST['firstname'];   
$lastname = $_POST['lastname']; 

$query = "SELECT user.user, user.firstname, user.lastname
          FROM user WHERE type = 'Owner' AND user LIKE '%$user%'";
```

If the person was search all 3, how would I put these into it?

```
 $query = "SELECT user.user, user.firstname, user.lastname 
           FROM user WHERE type = 'Owner' AND user LIKE '%$user%' 
           OR/AND type = 'Owner' AND fname LIKE '%$firstname%' 
           OR/AND type = 'Owner' AND lname LIKE '%$lastname%'";
```

This is what I have but does not work properly but I need something like OR/AND etce etc... Can someone please advise me how to do it? Thanks

Comment: **WARNING** Your code is susceptible to sql injection attacks.

Comment: Why're you going through your questions and changing the title and body to asadasdas asda sda sdas dasd asd asd?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will combine the WHERE statements if values are given

```
$user      = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user']); 
$firstname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['firstname']);   
$lastname  = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['lastname']);

$where[] = "type='Owner'";
if(strlen($user) > 0){
    $where[] = "user LIKE '%$user%'";
} 
if(strlen($firstname) > 0){
    $where[] = "firstname LIKE '%$firstname%'";
}
if(strlen($lastname) > 0){
    $where[] = "lastname LIKE '%$lastname%'";
}
$query = "SELECT user.user, user.firstname, user.lastname
          FROM user WHERE ". implode(' AND ', $where);
```